# Shell script to compress folders and copy it to another mount point

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I need a shell script that will compress .tar.gz the contents of a directory /hana/shared/backup_service/backups/30015/NDB/ and copy it to another folder:  /hana/data/.

but the files is named something based on date and time. So first run would create bck_20180121000002, second run would create bck_20180122000001, etc. Each backup will be a complete backup containing anything within that directory.

Comment: Are you asking for somebody to write a script for you? What have you tried? What were the results? What errors were received? Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using for years:

```
#!/bin/sh
## =====================================================
## backup sets: 'progs' (programs) or 'work'
## using "differential" technique (7 days per round)
## then copy to a mount point (USB)
##
## The mount point is defined in /etc/fstab as follows,
## which allow user to mount USB with disk label=BACKUP
## to the mount point /mnt/backup
##
## LABEL=BACKUP /mnt/backup auto user,noauto,noatime 0 0
##
## "Differential" technique:
## 1. find if there is a full backup within 7 days
## 2. if found, then backup only files that are changes since
##              the last full backup (diff backup)
## 3. if not, perform a full backup
## 4. to restore: tar xf the last full backup
##           and: tar xf the last diff backup
##
## Backups are encrypted using gnupg, placed in
## $HOME/BACKUPDIR
## Then check if the (USB) label=BACKUP exist, by checking
## if directory /mnt/backup/backup exists (it is a folder
## in that USB; ## if yes, then copy to that USB
##

## =====================================================

showUsage() {
    echo "`basename $0` progs | work [full]"
}

copyToOtherDisk() {
    [ -e "$1" ] || return
    if [ -b /dev/disk/by-label/BACKUP ]; then
        ## backup disk found
        local mounted=0
        if [ ! -d /mnt/backup/backup/ ]; then
            mount /mnt/backup && mounted=1
        fi
        if [ -d /mnt/backup/backup/ ]; then
            echo "cp -v $1 /mnt/backup/backup/."
            cp -v "$1" /mnt/backup/backup/.
            ls -la /mnt/backup/backup/
            sync
            df -h /mnt/backup
        fi
        [ $mounted = 1 ] && umount /mnt/backup
    fi
}


## =====================================================

timeStamp=`date +%y%m%d`

case "x$1" in
  xprogs)
    : ## details removed
    ;;
  xwork)
    if cd $HOME; then
        backupObj='folder1 folder2 file1 file2' ## detailed removed, replaced by samples
        ## find files modified within 7 days
        lastFullBackup=`find $HOME/BACKUPDIR/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -7 -name 'backup-work-*-full.tar.xz.gpg' | tail -n 1`
        if [ -z $lastFullBackup ] || [ "x$2" = "xfull" ]; then
            echo "Backup starts, full"
            echo "tar -cJf - $backupObj | gpg -c >$HOME/BACKUPDIR/backup-work-$timeStamp-full.tar.xz.gpg"
            tar -cJf - $backupObj | gpg -c >$HOME/BACKUPDIR/backup-work-$timeStamp-full.tar.xz.gpg
            copyToOtherDisk "$HOME/BACKUPDIR/backup-work-$timeStamp-full.tar.xz.gpg"
            echo "Backup ends"
        else
            echo "Backup starts, diff"
            echo "tar -N $lastFullBackup -cJf - $backupObj | gpg -c >$HOME/BACKUPDIR/backup-work-$timeStamp-diff.tar.xz.gpg"
            tar -N $lastFullBackup -cJf - $backupObj | gpg -c >$HOME/BACKUPDIR/backup-work-$timeStamp-diff.tar.xz.gpg
            copyToOtherDisk "$HOME/BACKUPDIR/backup-work-$timeStamp-diff.tar.xz.gpg"
            echo "Backup ends"
        fi
        cd -
    else
        echo "Error: $HOME"
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    showUsage
    ;;
esac

## vim:set ts=4:
## local variables:
## tab-width: 4
## end:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified script that is used daily:

```
    BackupName=$1
    today=`date +'%Y%m%d'`

help="Make backup in $startdir directory "
    usage="usage: $0 Backup-File-Name dir dir ..."
    if [  $# -lt 2 ]
    then
        echo $help
        echo $usage
        exit
    fi
    olddir=`pwd`
    tempdir=$$
    mkdir $tempdir
    shift 1
    # Each directory will be readed
    for dir in "$@"
    do
        #echo $dir
        directory=`dirname $dir`
        name=`basename $dir`

    cd $directory
    echo "Directory:$directory "
    # make tarball
    if [ -d $name ]
    then
            echo "Make tarball from $name"
            tar czvf $olddir/$tempdir/$name.$today.tar.gz $name
            mv $olddir/$tempdir/$name.$today.tar.gz $BackupName
    fi
done
cd $olddir
rmdir $tempdir
```

Your have to start the script :

```
/Path_to_script/Script.sh /hana/data /hana/shared/backup_service/backups/30015/NDB/
```

This is not the complete solution but should be largely helpful. I hope!

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
its very helpful, but it not exit from the script when it finish the copy ! maybe should i close it manually ? 
or it should work on background ?

Comment: Please be patient! Scrript works but if you want to see what it does set option "v" to tar command.
I've lost two lines by the copy and paste. I have edited the answer again.